# Assigning/Casting integers to pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define int int*

main(){
    int *p,q;
    p=(int *)5;
    q=10;
    printf("%d",q+p);
}
```

my question is that in line `p=(int *)5`, and `q=10` how it's working internally exactly because `p` and `q` are both pointer types, how is it possible that we can assign an integer value to pointer variable `q`?. One more thing how this type casting `p=(int*)5` working here ?

By using this formula we can answer

new address = old address+number * sizeof data type to which pointer is pointing

Comment: `#define int int*` - Evil mastermind:P

Comment: is it p = (int) 5 or p = (int *) 5 ?

Comment: Because of the #define, this is just nonsense code with no use in real world applications. There is no need to dwell on what it does.

Comment: @PetarMinchev Do you know the quote "never attribute to malice.." ?

Comment: @cnicutar - I haven't heard it till now. Nice one, thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define int int*` will replace `int *p, q` as `int* *p, q`. So Here `p` is double pointer to `int` and `q` is of type `int`.

For example consider the below program of your same logic in char

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#define char char*  
main()
{     
    char *p,q;     
    printf("%d, %d\n", sizeof(p), sizeof(q));
}
```

Output is

```
4, 1
```

`p=(int *)5;` - This statement also will be replaced like `p=(int* *)5;` by preporcessor. So its not throwing any warning.

so now `printf("%d",q+p);` will gives you `45` in case of 32 bit machine or `85` incase of 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers as indeed all data in a computer are, regardless of their logical meaning, physically implemented as numbers.

In the case of pointers, typically the numbers are virtual addresses; as such, when you manually assign a value to a pointer, you are setting a virtual address.

As it happens virtual addresses typically range from 0 to the address bus width of the CPU, so you get away with it - except of course that address has not been allocated and acccess it will cause an exception.

Sometimes however (typiclally embedded systems without virtual memory) the addresses are physical, not virtual, and some hardware devices (clocks, registers, etc) have known physical addresses, which are hand assigned to pointers and then the pointers are read from / written to.

Answer (score 0):

> p=(int *)5;

Variable p points on address 00000005.  If to try to change value to this address, It can lead to damage of other data and an unpredictable program runtime. 
For example

```
**p=10
```

causes exception

**Unhandled exception : Access violation writing location 0x00000005.**

Try **printf("%p",p)** before next operation to see initial address of poiner p.

> printf("%d",q+p);

Here magic of address arithmetics starts.. You can add address of pointer q to another pointer. So the pointer moves on new position in address space.  Try this:

```
p = p+ q
printf("%p",p);
```